# How to determine a cutoff based on a dataframe with stats (TN TP FN FP MCC F1) on thresholds?

Tags: r, threshold

I have gotten a dataframe with corresponding stats (TN TP FN FP MCC F1) on different thresholds (~10,000 thresholds). I'm wondering if there is any statistical methods that help determine the best thresholds based on these stats.

```
              t        TN        FN        TP         FP        F1       MCC
4270 0.01038365 0.9488243 0.6764706 0.3235294 0.05117566 0.4706892 0.3489976
4271 0.01038609 0.9488243 0.6764706 0.3235294 0.05117566 0.4706892 0.3489976
4272 0.01038854 0.9488243 0.6764706 0.3235294 0.05117566 0.4706892 0.3489976
4273 0.01039098 0.9488243 0.6764706 0.3235294 0.05117566 0.4706892 0.3489976
4274 0.01039343 0.9502075 0.6764706 0.3235294 0.04979253 0.4711632 0.3512697
4275 0.01039587 0.9502075 0.6764706 0.3235294 0.04979253 0.4711632 0.3512697
4276 0.01039832 0.9502075 0.6764706 0.3235294 0.04979253 0.4711632 0.3512697
4277 0.01040076 0.9502075 0.6764706 0.3235294 0.04979253 0.4711632 0.3512697
4278 0.01040320 0.9502075 0.6764706 0.3235294 0.04979253 0.4711632 0.3512697
4279 0.01040565 0.9502075 0.6764706 0.3235294 0.04979253 0.4711632 0.3512697
4280 0.01040809 0.9502075 0.6764706 0.3235294 0.04979253 0.4711632 0.3512697
```

The first column was the selected threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you want to find the best hyperparameter (threshold) for some binary classification, and those values above result from comparing the ground truth with your predictions.

**What threshold is the best**: It depends on what matters the most to you. If a high true positive rate is most important to you, you will have to choose a different threshold compared to whether the F1 score is considered most relevant. Only you know that.

Having said that, my experience is that MCC is often not very helpful. Furthermore, usually it makes most sense to use the F1 score, as it combines TP (often also called recall) and precision (you don't have a column for that).

Also note, that those columns in your table are a little redundant: E.g. TP = 1 - FN, i.e. you know TP once you are given FN.

So my suggestion is this: If you want to cover everything, just pick F1, TP, and TN, because then all ratios are fixed. Then compute as your criterion $c$ some weighted mean of those three, with weights chosen by you according to your scenario:
$$
c = w_1 F1 + w_2 TP + w_3 TN.
$$
Then choose the threshold that maximized c.